# Cant access the value of textfield element in action class

Tags: java, struts2

Here is the detail of the question

### In struts.......

```
<action name="ICUGramEntry" class="sfa.view.ICUAction">  
      <result name="success" type="tiles">icuGramTiles</result>  
</action>
```

### In ICUAction class.............

```
package sfa.view;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class ICUAction extends ActionSupport {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5693693076048575455L;

    private Map<String, String> FieldType;
    private String rad;
    public String execute(){
        System.out.println("ICUAction.execute()");
        setFieldType(new TreeMap<String, String>());
            setRad("ABC");
        getFieldType().put("003", "RBM");
        getFieldType().put("004", "ABM");
        getFieldType().put("005", "MSR");
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    public void setFieldType(Map<String, String> fieldType) {
        FieldType = fieldType;
    }
    public Map<String, String> getFieldType() {
        return FieldType;
    }
    public void setRad(String rad) {
    this.rad = rad;
}
public String getRad() {
    return rad;
}
}
```

In tiles......

```
<definition name="icuGramTiles" extends="baseLayout">
      <put-attribute name="body"   value="/icuGram.jsp"/>
</definition>
```

/icuGram.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">

<body>
<span class="pageHeader" >ICU GRAM</span>
<s:form action="ICUGramInsert"   method="POST" theme="simple">
<jsp:include page="/headerbar.jsp"></jsp:include>
<s:select id="fieldtype" list="FieldType" name="TYPE" cssClass="smallSelect" cssStyle="width:200px;" 

"></s:select>
<s:textfield name="rad"></s:textfield>

</body>
</html>
```

i can view the value in textfield on jsp as

> ABC

as set in action

> setRad("ABC");

from here ICUGramInsert action is called

```
<action name="ICUGramInsert" 
             class="sfa.view.ICUGramInsert"  >  
             <result type="chain">/Detail.jsp</result>  
         </action>
```

and it goes to sfa.view.DetailAction

```
package sfa.view;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
public class ICUGramInsert extends ActionSupport {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String TYPE;
    public String execute()
    {
        System.out.println("DetailAction.execute()...1"+this.getTYPE());
        System.out.println("DetailAction.execute()...2"+this.getrad());
        return SUCCESS;
    }
        public void setTYPE(String tYPE) {
        TYPE = tYPE;
    }

    public String getTYPE() {
        return TYPE;
    }
}
```

i get the console out put  of this.getTYPE() as follows=============>
DetailAction.execute()...1null
DetailAction.execute()...2null

Comment: more info required.Re you invoking the same execute method after submitting from jsp,what is the value you are submitting from jsp.Moreover you have not declared `FIRST_NAME` as a variable in this class

Comment: Show complete SfaAction class (including package declaration), the JSP's at issue and the struts.xml (if any, if conventions are at work please list the previous sources in a fully qualified way).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you have used ServletRequestAware interceptor here since Struts2 automatically perform data transfer both way.

Regarding your execute method its signature is not as per the Framework it should be

```
public String execute () throw exception {

}
```

Comment: That's not entirely true. If an interface defines that a method can throw an exception, the actual implementing method is allowed to not throw the exception. Therefore 'throws Exception' is optional for an action class.

Answer (score 0):

> However, when I try to retrieve this value after page is submitted in action I am not able to get this value ... by getParameter method on the request object.

That sounds like you aren't submitting the value to the action from your form.

Make sure that you are:

- Submitting the value of first name to the action via your form
- Prefer having an instance field called `firstName` that has a getter and a setter, rather than accessing the String values directly from the `HttpServletRequest`

Comment: Steven actually i cant even submit from from the <s:submit/> button.  I need to handle the onclick event of that submit. Like <s:submit onclick="funSub1();"/>  and in script function funSub1(){ document.getElementById("...").submit();} and again there is another problem that if submitted the page with this way and the same page comes for next entry once it is submitted i cant submit for the next time i come to this page, it throws a script error. Is the problem with javascript...